# Cannot open graph .gcx file saved by Grapher

Tags: macos, catalina, grapher

I'm facing an issue where I am unable to re-open any saved graphs that have a contour plot inside. For example, if you plot *sin(x)*cos(y)* and save it, you will not be able to reopen it in Grapher. It will just say: **The document “test.gcx” could not be opened**.

Example of a plot that I cannot save and re-open:

[image]

Comment: I have had the same problem. Do not remember if before or after I updated the OS.

Comment: It's sad that Apple is not updating this great tool. There isn't even an option to file a suggestion for Grapher afaik.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's grapher does not save and reopen correctly files without real equation (with the sign equal)
Another problem is with upgrading the os, and the security : sometimes you have to allow (with "open anyway" box in the security preference panel) the system to load a file previously created.

Answer (score -1):

If you save your file to your home directory or a directory under home, you should be able to open the file later. I have Big Sur on my 2020 intel iMac and I made a 3d contour plot and saved it to my home directory. I was about to open the file with Grapher.